# Overloading Operators: Does the 1st parameter correspond to the left operand and the 2nd one to the right operand?

Tags: c++, stream, operator-overloading

When writing a **non-member** function to overload an operator, does the 1st parameter correspond to the left operand and the 2nd parameter to the right operand?

I was trying to overload the "<<" operator to use it like this:

```
stream << ClassA << ClassB
```

Below is an example where `FeetInches` is a class with member variables `feet` and `inches`  .

Is that why this parameter order works:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &strm, const FeetInches &obj)
{
   strm << obj.feet << " feet, " << obj.inches << " inches";
   return strm;
}
```

--

but this parameter order doesn't work?

```
ostream &operator<<(const FeetInches &obj, ostream &strm)
{
   strm << obj.feet << " feet, " << obj.inches << " inches";
   return strm;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ostream` comes 1st as we don't have any invoking object here.

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &strm, const FeetInches &obj)
{
   strm << obj.feet << " feet, " << obj.inches << " inches";
   return strm;
}
```

as `cout<<obj<<endl;` will be interpreted as `operator<<(cout,obj);`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it all works as you said.